# $P$ prime implies $V(P)$ irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $P\subset k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ be a prime ideal. Is it true that the variety $V(P)$ is irreducible?

This is easy to show when $k$ is algebraically closed. Is it also true in general?

Comment: As explained by catfish below, the answer is "no". This is not to be confused with the result that if you start with an irreducible subset (in the Zariski topology)  $X\subset k^n$, then its ideal $I(X)\subset k[x_1,...,x_n]$ **is** prime, independently of whether $k$ is algebraically closed or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Consider this counter example taken from the exercises of Fulton's algebraic curves book:

Let $P = (f)\subseteq \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ where $f = y^2 + x^2(x-1)^2$. We have that $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. To see this, note that as a polynomial in $(\mathbb{R}[x])[y]$, since it's degree $2$, it is reducible iff it has a root in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. But $y^2 = -x^2(x-1)^2$ has no solution in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Now since $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ is a UFD, $f$ is prime, thus so is the ideal it generates (i.e. $P$ is prime).

However, $V(P) = \{z\in\mathbb{A}^{2}(\mathbb{R})\mid f(z) = 0\} = \{(0,0),(1,0)\}$ is reducible. Also, in this case $V(P)$ would be just be called an algebraic set since it is not irreducible.

Comment: I think you are confusing irreducible with absolutely irreducible. A prime ideal as above defines an irreducible variety, which may or may not be absolutely irreducible- that is, the prime may not remain prime over the algebraic closure of the base field. So, the answer to the question is that yes, $V(P)$ is irreducible in the usual sense.

Comment: Of course at an advanced, scheme-theoretic, level a prime ideal of a ring defines  an irreducible scheme, but this is almost trivial and not very exciting. Catfish's  answer is however quite correct if one considers that $V(P)\subset k^n$ is a subset of $k^n$ endowed with its Zariski topology,  a  most  reasonable interpretation  in an introductory  algebraic geometry course. Since the given answer gives a  clear and pretty counterexample showing non irreducibility,  +1.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg thank you, I am at an introductory level of learning algebraic geometry and was not aware of the interpretation mentioned by Mohan.